# Simple switch to control power

Tags: power, switches, low-power

I've been search for days for the right answer to this question but have drawn blanks so far so thought i would ask it here.

I'm trying to create a simple circuit to control power to a device. The switch receives a signal (HIGH) and completes the circuit. Normally I'd go with something like a 4066 but the power may range from 5-22v. Is there a switch out there that can do this?

Thanks in advance guys.

[image]

Edit: As pointed out I forgot to add the most important bit being the current which would be max 600mA.

Comment: What is the voltage of "HIGH?" (I suppose all these things can share a common ground.) What current compliance is required? How much "voltage drop" is allowed across the switch? Is a relay unaccepable for some reason?

Comment: Hi @jonk. Max current will be around 600mA, with as little voltage drop as possible. I hadn't considered a relay as I'm not up to speed on their workings but if there is one you can recommend I'll definitely look into it. Cheers, T

Comment: If the supply was lower, how could a 4066 ever of been a candidate at 600 mA? Fix your question up with all the necessary facts please so as not to waste anybody's time?

Comment: You'll need to specify the voltage of your "signal" and its current compliance (ability to drive a load.) You will also need to specify the frequency of operation of this switch and what kind of delays you can accept in it responding to the signal. And anything else you can think of that may be of use to someone trying to help.

Comment: it seems like you're describing a relay, either electromechanical or a mosfet-based solid-state relay.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @jonk I believe the voltage of the signal would 5v. Please excuse my lack of details, I'm very new to this sort of stuff. I'm more than willing to learn when pointed in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple circuit that can be a electronic power switch for your load. This circuit can be made quite small as M1 is just a SOT-23 and M2 is a SO-8. It offers a soft start capability by limiting the turn on time to the load as a nice 10msec linear ramp. Turn off time is a generous 250msec. The shown MOSFETs are rated suitably for the 24V input shown but will work equally well with an input voltage from 5V up to 24V.

[image]

If you do not want the soft start capability and desire fast switching times at the load then remove C1 and R3 and change the value of R2 to 220 ohms. This will permit switch on times less than 1usec and an off time of about 30usec.

The input to the circuit can be a logic level signal from an MCU with either a 0V to 3.3V or 0V to 5V swing. The 0V level at the input shuts off the switch and the positive level voltage turns the switch on.